# Loop in C# with a checkBox and intervals

Tags: c#, loops, intervals

I would like that when I check the checkBox1 this code is repeated until the checkBox1 is unchecked:

```
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "1");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

And here is the code to execute when checkBox1 is unchecked:

```
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
```

And this is what I did:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "1");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
                MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Sleeping / looping inside a Clicked-Handler .... seems like a bad choice.

Comment: How would you exit the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a timer. Something like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
        MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "1");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        MemLib.WriteMemory("base+02DB12E8", "float", "500");
        MemLib.WriteMemory("base+025EBA28", "int", "0");
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8